# Linked List steps

Tags: java, linked-list

I have this project to do and I don't know what steps to pierced

Write a java program to store employee information in a linked list, the program
should implement the following functions:

- **function** 
  task
- **Insert a new employee** 
  Add an new employee to the linked
                                        list and store employee's information
                                        ( ID, name, address, department,
                                         salary)
- **Update employee information** 
  Modify an existing employee's
                                          information (change address and
                                         salary only). You should ask for
                                          employee ID to update his/her
                                          information
- **Remove an employee** 
  Remove the employee using
                                          employee ID from the linked list

The program should display the list of functions, and ask the user to enter the number
of function that he/she wants to do, then perform the function as it is required in the previous table.

this is what I did

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class LinkedListEmployee {
    
    //------------start of employee class--------
    private class Employee {
        private String empNumber;
        private String name;
        private String department;
        private int empTest;
        private double salary;
        public Employee() {
            empNumber = null;
            empTest= 0;
            name = null;
            department = null;
            salary = 0.0;
        }
        
    }
    //------------end of employee class--------
    
    
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
            LinkedList<Employee> empTest = new LinkedList<Employee>();
            System.out.println("\nMENU\n1.Add Employee\n2.Update");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = in.nextInt();
            if (choice == 2)
                System.out.println("Enter employee’s name");
            String nm = in.nextLine();
           update(nm, empTest);
        }
        public static void update(String namePara, LinkedList<Employee> empTest) {
            ListIterator<Employee> litr = empTest.listIterator();
            Employee tempEmp;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (litr.hasNext()) {
                tempEmp=litr.next();
                if (tempEmp.name.equals(namePara)) {
                    System.out.println("Enter new address");
                    String add = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter new salary");
                    String sal = in.nextLine();
                    //tempEmp.Empaddress = add;
                    tempEmp.salary = Double.parseDouble(sal);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

It finally work is that it ?? or there are more steps to go !! referring to the question ?

Please help me know the steps

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: listIterator<Integer> litr = empTest.listIterator();       cannot find symbol - class listlterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment in response to what error you are getting ("listIterator litr = empTest.listIterator(); cannot find symbol - class listlterator"):

The type `listIterator` is unknown, you are looking for `ListIterator`, so change

```
listIterator<Integer> litr = empTest.listIterator();
```

to

```
ListIterator<Integer> litr = empTest.listIterator();
```

---

Edit for the next error after then: "ListIterator litr = empTest.listIterator(); cannot find symbol - variable empTest":

That list is only visible within the [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) of the main method since it's declared in there. One possibility is to pass the list along with the method call, so change

```
public static void Update(String name) {
```

to

```
public static void update(String name, LinkedList<employee> empTest) {
```

and pass the missing list into the update method from your main method:

```
update(nm, empTest); //instead of Update(nm);
```

Alternatively, you can widen the scope of the list and declare it for the entire class, as mentioned in the comments by @Dude, but this should be handled with care, as this heightens the retained state of the object (or even class in this case) in question.

Aside: Types are Capitalized in Java (employee should be Employee), whereas variables and methods start with lower case (Update() should be update()). Take a look at [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), please.

Comment: Um, the type `java.util.ListIterator` has been part of the java framework since Java 1.2. Can you please double-check if you are not having any other typos for that line? All I had to do was correct the capitalization of the `litr` declaration. Other things you can try: Do an Organize-Imports and a Clean+Rebuild, or paste the error (or snap a screenshot and link to it) in your question.

Comment: you should make empTest a class variable like empNumber

Comment: I did update my answer and question, I'm still trying to fix the variable error :( and he the website don't allow me to insert pic

Comment: As for the pictures, as a new user, you'll have to post images to an image hoster and link to it with a plain text link. Someone else might then even edit it into your post.

Comment: I finally did it, it compiled without an errors :D                                           are there other steps ?? or that solve the question ??

Comment: Well you have evolved your original question with all the solved errors from the first two editions of my answer, and I guess now the rest of the requirements waits for you? :) StackOverflow usually does not provide full-fledged solutions to functional requirements (aka you have to figure out yourself how to solve the functional task at hand), but "only" helps with very specific technical or algorithmic problems you encounter. We can't do all the thinking, you know :) So if you have any more of these probs, feel free to post them as new questions (instead of weaving them into your old one ;))